# echo PHP array with while loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

I'm using a while loop to echo a PHP array :

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "db");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,4";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 echo'<section>
        <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
             <h2 class="bold">title</h2>
               <hr> ';

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                 echo'
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-push-3">
                    <div class="portfolio-wrapper">   
                        <div class="portfolio-single">
                            <div class="portfolio-thumb">
                                <a href="'.$row['link']." target="_blank">                                                        <img src="'.$row['image'].'" class="img-responsive" alt="'.$row['alt']."></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="portfolio-info" dir="rtl">
                            <a href="'.$row['link2']." target="_self"><h2>                     </h2>
                                <h6>'.$row['title'].</h6>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';

            }
                echo'
                </div>
                    </div>
                    </section';
            }   

            ?>
```

This code works fine for me but the problem is that i need to echo 4 different

for example :

```
   first will be: <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-push-9">
   second: <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-push-3">
   third: <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-pull-3">
   last: <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">
```

any ideas how can i accomplish this structure using a while loop ?

Comment: Keep a counter variable, use it to determine which class to use then increment the counter variable for the next iteration of your loop.

Comment: Like robbie said. Something like this `$array = array(
    '0' => 'col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-push-9'
    '1' => 'col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-push-3',
    '2' => 'col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-pull-3',
    '3' => 'col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-pull-9');
$count = 0;
while(){
 div... class=$array[$count];
 ...
 count ++
}`

Done in notepad so not correct syntax but you get the idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a counter, and put your classes into an array like this:

```
$classes = [
    "col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-push-9",
    "col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-push-3",
    "col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-pull-3",
    "col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-pull-9"
];

$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($i > 3) {
        $i = 0;
    }
    ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $classes[$i]; ?>">
        Your content comes here
    </div>
    <?php
    $i++;
}
```

**NOTE**

This is resets the counter, if there is no index like that in the array. Your script assumes, that you will get always 4 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "db");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,4";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$i = 1;
$count = count($result);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 echo'<section>
        <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
             <h2 class="bold">title</h2>
               <hr> ';

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                if($i==1){echo '<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-push-9">';}
                elseif($i == $count){echo '<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">';}
                elseif($i%2 == 0){echo '<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-push-3">';}
                elseif($i%3 == 0){echo '<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">';}

                 echo'
                        <div class="portfolio-wrapper">   
                            <div class="portfolio-single">
                                <div class="portfolio-thumb">
                                    <a href="'.$row['link']." target="_blank">                                                        <img src="'.$row['image'].'" class="img-responsive" alt="'.$row['alt']."></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="portfolio-info" dir="rtl">
                                <a href="'.$row['link2']." target="_self"><h2>                     </h2>
                                    <h6>'.$row['title'].</h6>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
                    $i =$i+1;
            }
                echo'
                </div>
                    </div>
                    </section';
            }   

?>
```